# Limit the text input boundaries on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am developing an app for my company but i am no expert on obj-C programming language. I've tried to find some answers on the internet but no success at all. The solution to the problem may be simple, but i am unable to solve it.

I want to limit the text so it fits inside the text box. What is happening right now is as i start typing and it flows on the first line forever and do not change drop to the second line when it hits the box boundaries.

```
    otherdetails = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:otherdetailsf];
    otherdetails.text = otherdetailstxt;
    [otherdetails.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
    [otherdetails.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
    otherdetails.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    otherdetails.clipsToBounds = YES;
    otherdetails.delegate = self;
    otherdetails.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
    otherdetails.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

Thats what happens when i type a lot on the text field....

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TextView`instead of text field if you need to support multiple lines of text whenever the text reaches the end of a line.

**From Documentation:**

> The UITextView class implements the behavior for a scrollable,
>   multiline text region. The class supports the display of text using
>   custom style information and also supports text editing. You typically
>   use a text view to display multiple lines of text, such as when
>   displaying the body of a large text document.

So your code should be:

```
 otherDetails=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:otherdetailsf];
    otherDetails.text=@"";
    [otherDetails.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
    [otherDetails.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
    otherDetails.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    otherDetails.clipsToBounds = YES;
    otherDetails.delegate = self;

    // otherDetails.contentMode=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

in viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>
@property (strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UITextView *mytextview;

@end
```

in viewcontroller.m

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mytextview;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)addTextView
{

    [mytextview setText:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet"];
    mytextview.delegate = self;
     [self.view addSubview:mytextview];

    mytextview.delegate = self;

}

    -(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:
    (NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
        if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
            [textView resignFirstResponder];
        }
        return YES;}

-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    NSLog(@"Did begin editing");
}
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    NSLog(@"Did Change");

}
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    NSLog(@"Did End editing");

}
-(BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
@end
```